# the path of backend service, database and push notification deployment for production

Tags: node.js, react-native, rest, deployment, production

I have been involved lots of companies' production projects but I didn't build myself. I built a react native app. But I am really confused where I should store data, backend service and push notification also. Which platform can be wise chose to use all 3 of them. Backend rest service will be nodejs. Unfortunately, I spend my 1 year azure free trial. I need to first try my app performance and users should use my app also, then should be free for trial to some amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you developed your app to be in container you can use k8s as a service from one of the providers.
All of the top cloud providers have a multitude of solutions so its up to your arch and funds to decided where to go with it.
I do not think anyone will be able to give you better answer then yourself as your know the intimate details of your architecture.